# How to install Wordpress with HTTP/2

Tags: wordpress, http2

I want to install WordPress. Sounds easy, but unexpected errors occurs.
The install page loaded with only html content (no style ). when you click next, a
"Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."
All requested file permissions and .htaccess are verified.
The server have let's encrypt SSL and HTTP/2 enabled.
Any Idea

Comment: Check with your hosting. Wordpress installation has no problem with http or ssl is probably some configuration of your hosting server

Answer (score 0):

I never had any problems installing Wordpress on a http2 server.

If you are on a linux server with shell-access: navigate in your wordpress directory and try this in the SSH console to set the permissions right:

```
chown USER:GROUP -R *
```

chown all files & directories (recursive) to the Webservers USER & GROUP. Replace USER & GROUP with the CORRECT (!) values depending on your hosting. Something like www-data:www-data for example).
You can find the right USER & GROUP if you check another directory or file that is automatically created by the hosting (error docs or the httpdocs folder - depends on your hosting)

Then:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

(set all subdirectories to 755)

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

(set all files to to 644)

Regards Tom

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not working same 403 forbidden